# check-box always returns true .getSelection();

Tags: java, eclipse, checkbox, swt

In a Java project I am using swt widget button as a check box.
[I have read the java docs](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Button.html) and the function i need to check whether the box is checked or not seems to be Button.getSelection(). In my implementation, whether i have selected the box or not, It always seems to return true.

setChecks is called at the start and getFilter is then called when a button is pressed. 
the, check boxes appear as expected and I can deselect some of them, but when i press my button the print line in getFilter returns true for each of the buttons.

```
void setChecks(String[] s){
    button=new Button[s.length];
    bool = new boolean[button.length];
    for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){
        button[i] = new Button(shell,  SWT.CHECK);
        button[i].setSelection(true);
        button[i].setBounds(449, 209+(20*i), 174, 16);
        button[i].setText(s[i]);
        //System.out.println(s[i]);
    }
}
private boolean[] getFilter() {
    bool = new boolean[button.length];
    for (int i=0; i<bool.length;i++){
        bool[i]=button[i].getSelection();
        System.out.println(button[i].getSelection());
    }
    return bool;
}
```

Edit:

amended code:

```
button[i].addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener(){
            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
            }
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Button b = (Button)arg0.getSource();
                b.setSelection(!b.getSelection());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Just a note: It's bad practice to use `setBounds()` unless absolutely necessary, use a `Layout` instead. If you haven't already, please read: [Understanding Layouts in SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html).

Comment: That looks good and i may convert over later, GUI objects aren't my strong point so am currently using an eclipse gui editor which produces the bounds. I am working on functionality when it comes to design, i may convert it over then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always setting it to `true` by

`button[i].setSelection(true);`

that's why you always get true. You need to set the `button` once you make a selection. Do you have a listener attached to it. You have to use

```
 void addSelectionListener(SelectionListener listener)
```

Adds the listener to the collection of listeners who will be notified when the control is selected by the user, by sending it one of the messages defined in the SelectionListener interface.

Please read the documentation on [SelectionListener](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/events/SelectionListener.html). You have to use

`void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)`

Sent when selection occurs in the control.

`void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e)`

Sent when default selection occurs in the control.

Comment: I knew i was setting it to true using that, i wanted the box's to start selected, and does when the user clicks on the box when running not automatically toggle the selection? i presumed it did.

Comment: No, it doesn't automatically get set when you do in the control. You need to attach the listener and listen to event and implement the selection programmatically

Comment: I have added my amended code, but this seems to be changing the checkboxs to false and then back to true when i click it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution i have found, and then accessing bool, instead of calling getFilters.

```
void setChecks(String[] s){
    button=new Button[s.length];
    bool = new boolean[button.length];
    for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){
        button[i] = new Button(shell,  SWT.CHECK);
        button[i].setSelection(true);
        bool[i]=true;
        button[i].addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener(){
            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
            }
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
                Button b = (Button)arg0.getSource();
                for (int i=0;i<button.length;i++){
                    if (button[i].getText()==b.getText())bool[i]=!bool[i];
                }
            }
        });
        button[i].setBounds(449, 209+(20*i), 174, 16);
        button[i].setText(s[i]);
    }
}
```